# How to automatically add row at first row in google sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I have google sheet which i am editing every day.

actual date is at **first row + first column**..

I want to create **script/makro** to create this row automatically each new day new row.. or add whole month.. SO each new month it would create at the top of table 30-31 new rows..

sorting like this
**-> first row in table == actual date**
Wednesday 21st November 2018 .....next columns.....
Tuesday 20th November 2018 .....next columns.....
Monday 19th November 2018 .....next columns.....
.
.
.
.

I found just some functions like getLastrow() but opposite nope... I would like to use just google sheets online.. no excel!

```
//this is example how i add lastrow... but its not correct, also it just copy paste last row.. 
// global 
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

function onOpen() {
    var menu = [{name:"Add New Last Row", functionName:"addRow"}];
    ss.addMenu("Extra", menu);
}

function addRow() {
    var sh = ss.getActiveSheet(), lRow = sh.getLastRow(); 
    var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(lRow,1,1,lCol);
    sh.insertRowsAfter(lRow, 1);
    range.copyTo(sh.getRange(lRow+1, 1, 1, lCol), {contentsOnly:false});
}
```

Thanks for any help..

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use insertRowsBefore(beforePosition, howMany). Put in the first position, and then the number of rows you would like to insert.

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet.insertRowsBefore(beforePosition, howMany)
```

Answer (score 0):

I edit function like this:

```
function addRow() {
  var sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var lCol = sh.getLastColumn(), range = sh.getRange(2,1,1,lCol);
  //range.copyTo(sh.getRange(2, 1, 1, lCol), {contentsonly: false});
  sh.insertRowsBefore(2, 28);
}
```

but i still cant figure out how to automatically do it.. and how to autoincrement date